# Test scroll inside select using react testing library

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I am testing a select element from the "react-select" library

//SelectApi.js

```
 <Select
                isClearable={false}
                value={value}
                options={options}
                className='react-select'
                classNamePrefix='select'
                theme={selectThemeColors}
                aria-label={ariaLabel}
                onMenuScrollToBottom={handleScroll}
                onInputChange={handleDBInputChange}
                onChange={handleChange}
            />
```

But I don't know how to test the "onMenuScrollToBottom" part to activate the "handleScroll" function

```
 const handleScroll = () => {
        let newSkip = skip + limit
        setSkip(newSkip)
    }
```

For unit tests I am using the library "react-testing-library"

//SelectApi.test.js

```
    test("scroll in select", async () => {

        let value = jest.fn()
        let updateValue = jest.fn()
        let apiUrl = "/api/promoters/data"
        let ariaLabel = "selectPromoterFilter"

        const promotersOptions = [
            {
                id: 0,
                label: "Select Promoter",
                value: ""
            },
            {
                id: 1,
                label: "Ernesto Luna Hernández",
                value: 1
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                label: "María Fernanda Lopéz Barilla",
                value: 2
            },
            {
                id: 3,
                label: "Ricardo Gómez Robles",
                value: 3
            },
            {
                id: 4,
                label: "Ricardo Gómez Robles",
                value: 3
            },
            {
                id: 5,
                label: "Ricardo Gómez Robles",
                value: 5
            },
            {
                id: 6,
                label: "Ricardo Gómez Robles",
                value: 6
            },
            {
                id: 7,
                label: "Ricardo Gómez Robles",
                value: 7
            },
            {
                id: 8,
                label: "Ricardo Gómez Robles",
                value: 8
            },
            {
                id: 9,
                label: "Ricardo Gómez Robles",
                value: 9
            },
            {
                id: 10,
                label: "Final",
                value: 10
            }
        ]
        jest.spyOn(axios, 'get').mockResolvedValueOnce({ data: promotersOptions});

        let container
        await act(async () => {
            container = render(
                <Router>
                    <Provider store={store}>
                        <SelectApi
                            value={value}
                            updateValue={updateValue}
                            apiUrl={apiUrl}
                            ariaLabel={ariaLabel}
                        />
                    </Provider>
                </Router>
            )
        })


        
        const selectPromoter = container.queryByLabelText(ariaLabel)
        if (selectPromoter) {
            await act(async () => {
                fireEvent.click(selectPromoter)
                fireEvent.scroll(selectPromoter, { target: { scrollY: 400 } });

            })

        }



    })
```

The solution of how I can activate the scroll inside the select to complete the coverage of the component

Comment: Hi @Laura welcome, check if `selectorPromoter` corresponds to the element that should be scrolled

Comment: Yes it is that one, because for the unit test of selecting an element it works perfectly